# Format "formatless" date field in excel

Tags: excel, date

In Excel I have a column (date field) in the form: daymonthyear hourminutes. An example is: 20042015 0916 (all this in a single cell). How can it be automatically modified to the more commonly format 20/04/2015 09:16?

Comment: What version are you using?  You should be able to change the unix number by right-clicking > Properties >Number > Date Format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've got is a string and Excel won't be able to interpret as date. You can convert it to a date time value:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,5,4),MID(A1,3,2),LEFT(A1,2))+TIME(MID(A1,10,2),RIGHT(A1,2),0)
```